# Can't boot after hardware upgrade

Tags: windows-7, boot

today I've just changed completely my hardware: a new case, new CPU (i5 replaced amd athlon 5000+), new motherboard, new ram... I've kept only the GPU and HDD.

But now it won't boot. I can see it start l starts windows but soon enough there was a bsod and then reboot. Finally, with safe mode, I learnt that avast was the culprit so I rebuilt the old configuration and uninstalled it.

But now it reboots every time at CLASSPNP.sys so I can't use my new computer :'(

Please tell me that I do not need to reinstall everything. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: changing the cpu from amd to intel would be a huge problem, personally I think using sysprep is the only way to reset this. But you still will not have the correct drivers installed.

Comment: If you had Windows 7 OEM you will not be able to activate Windows 7 if you did boot it. OEM is tied to motherboard. Like the answer below, you probably will have to upgrade to Windows 8

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you are expecting rather a lot from an OS if you think you can replace the motherboard and change CPU manufacturer and still expect the old OS to work without a hiccup!

Whilst you might be able to run a recovery on it, I'm not sure how much I'd want to trust it. You might be better off trying an upgrade to Windows 8.1 on it.

Comment: Why? If he ran SysPrep he wouldn't have this problem there are other methods like Acronis True Image that can restore an image to different hardware, which basically uses SysPrep to do so

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer all. So I'd need to reinstall everything. My dad said that what's wee would do at the end. For sysprep it is only after a clone. however i cant access it.

Comment: I've installed several games and I'd rather avoid reinstalling them all. Since I've installed them on an another disk (H:) is there a way to back them up?

Comment: As I said, you may be able to run recovery on it without necessarily loosing everything. However I would say that Windows 8 is much better at this than 7. The problem with installed apps is that they tend to put "stuff" all over the place and it is nigh-on impossible to capture all of that and put it on another computer. You will have a variety of files and registry entries. Some of those, especially for games, are specific to the hardware so it is very unlikely indeed that the game would work anyway I'm afraid. The best you can hope for is keeping any saved games, they should transfer OK.